# laravel error : Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

After I pull my project in git, I get this error. It's my 1st time to encounter this error.

The error is:

```
Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script.
```

my Model

```
 <?php
 
namespace App\Models;
```

The version of my Laravel is 5.5.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There is an empty space before the `<?php` tag. Remove it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
```

Answer (score 2):

If problem continue you have to remove bom from file via notepad++

Answer (score 2):

Also check that your IDE create UTF-8 files (with NO BOM) 
[UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).
For example, in phpStorm Settings / Editor / File Encodings -> Create UTF-8 files: with NO BOM